# Merge mp4 files

Tags: video, merge, mp4, wireshark

I am trying to download video from site and for that i start Wireshark and load the page, after that I saw that I got something like 10 segmental mp4 files. I tried  to play them but it  failed so I guess I need to merge them somehow.
Any idea?

Comment: You merge them using ffmpeg once you downloaded them. (Considering this is legal).

Comment: hello i tried to use this answer  :
http://superuser.com/questions/607383/concat-two-mp4-files-with-ffmpeg-without-losing-quality
but it doesn't work it write for me: input.txt:No such file or directory. and i opened file the called like this. @iKiWiXz

Comment: How do you know they are mp4?

Comment: @szatmary because in the wireshark it's written "mp4 file"

Comment: @user3100708 Are you sure you've got input.txt in the directory you execute ffmpeg from ?

Comment: @iKiWiXz yes i am sure